# How can I join the regions from individual estimators in a random forest?

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I have an sklearn random forest which contains 3 estimators or trees. For a particular sample, I’ve used the “decision path” feature to extract the individual estimators’ decisions which are a set of constraints. I now have tuples as follows <set of constraints, probability> for each of the 3 estimators.

I wanted to know how I could join the “set of constraints” of all the individual estimators to get a combined decision region, i.e., a region where all points inside when passed to the RF will map to that particular sample (class). I am looking for the region to be as precise as possible. In the overlapping regions, the lower probability should be selected.

Any help or insights would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Just for curiosity, can you show us some examples of those tuples <set of constraints, probability>?

Comment: ( x1>6.5, x2>=7.5, Prob = 0.67 ) , (x1>7, x2>8, Prob = 0.71) This would be an example of two regions with overlapping parts that have different probabilities

Answer (score 0):

I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66714568/automatically-simplify-redundant-arithmetic-relations) is what you're looking for, just iterate this approach for every set containing multiple rules and you're done. I'd implement it considering different intersections (at first all the intersections of 2 rules, then all those of 3 rules and so on) because they will decrease the bigger is the set of rules you're using for the calculation

Comment: I am looking to construct a decision region wherein, if I give the system a point in the overlapping regions, it should return the average probability of the overlapping regions.

Comment: You can do it by:
- finding all overlaps and rating their probabilities
- compute calculate in which overlap the point is
- return the probability of that region

Comment: Any idea on how to achieve this in python for a region? If I have these regions - ( x1>6.5, x2>=7.5, Prob = 0.67 ) , (x1>7, x2>8, Prob = 0.71) and my test region is  (x1>6.75 and x2 >7.75), How can I get the section of the test region (or point) with the lowest probability?